# Chatter app to Salesforce 1/Assigned Mobile Device/Unable to edit record

Tags: salesforce1-app

I was able to edit records via Chatter for Android but I've lost that ability. How can I get that ability again?
My profile has all the CRUD permission and record type access..basically the system admin profile..

I then upgraded Chatter app to Salesforce 1(The login record shows Salesforce1/Chatter for Android)
Still I'm unable to edit the record..

I then realized user record still has an 'Assigned Mobile Device' record which shows in the Device status 'Data Size Limit Exceeded.' Could this be preventing me to edit the records which otherwise I can access via browser? Also, Is the 'Assigned Mobile Device' setting still required for Salesforce 1 app? Could it be incompatibility with Android version?

Requesting some insights/help!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things here.

If you login into regular Salesforce, so via your browser, do you still have edit rights there? (try opening a record, clicking the edit and save)
If not, then the issue is not related to just the Salesforce1 app and you lost edit rights somehow. For that, you best check with your system administrator to get them back.

Assigned mobile devices is something that is only still applicable for the Salesforce Classic application. According to me, this isn't used anymore for Salesforce1.

It's indeed very likely that you have an android version that is not supported by Salesforce1.
The minimum android version is 4.2 (jellybean). If you would install the app on an older android version, it will install the old chatter mobile app and there it's not possible to edit records.
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_salesforce1_requirements.htm

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It was the old android version causing the issue.
Thanks for taking the time out for the question!!

Answer (score 0):

try this
Setup | Customize | Chatter | Settings | Enable Publisher Actions.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Sindoora.
Another user with same access as mine can easily edit such record. The difference: The other user is using Iphone and my profile still has 'Assigned Mobile Device.' Any other suggestions?